The tilde species
Consider a combinatorial species $F$, that is, an action of the symmetric group $\mathfrak S_n$ on a finite set $F[n]$.  Recall that the elements of $F[n]$ are called structures.  Furthermore, recall the notation $F[\sigma](s)$ for the structure in $F[n]$ obtained by acting with $\sigma\in\mathfrak S_n$ on $s$.
Joyal defined the species $\tilde F$ (roughly) as follows:

let $\tilde F[n] = \{(s, \alpha)\in F[n]\times\mathfrak S_n | F[\alpha](s) = s\}$, that is, the set of pairs $(s, \alpha)$ such that $\alpha$ is an automorphism of $s$, and
let $\tilde F[\sigma](s, \alpha) = (F[\sigma](\alpha), \sigma\circ\alpha\circ\sigma^{-1})$.

The main motivation to introduce this species is, as far as I know, the proof of the substitution formula, i.e., the computation of the character of $F\circ G$ (which, for 'molecular' species, is essentially the wreath product).
Playing with a new package I developed with Travis Scrimshaw and Mainak Roy for SageMath (https://github.com/sagemath/sage/pull/38446), I came to wonder what is known about $\tilde F$.
As pointed out on page 21 in Joyal, Andre, Une théorie combinatoire des séries formelles, Adv. Math. 42, 1-82 (1981). ZBL0491.05007, $\widetilde{F+G} = \tilde F + \tilde G$ and $\widetilde{F G} = \tilde F \tilde G$, so we can restrict attention to atomic species.  Recall that a species is called atomic if the corresponding permutation group is indecomposable under direct product.
The number of isomorphism types of $\tilde F$ is the number of conjugacy classes of the corresponding permutation group.
It is not hard to see that $\tilde F = \frac{n!}{|F[n]|} F$ if $F$ is an atomic species corresponding to an abelian group of degree $n$.
Finally, for the species $E_n$ of sets, $\tilde E_n$ is, by definition, the species of permutations, i.e., the adjoint action of the symmetric group.
The two other 'classical' families of atomic species which do not correspond to an abelian group are

$P_n$ be the species of polygons, corresponding to the dihedral groups, and
$E^\pm_n$ be the species of oriented sets, corresponding to the alternating groups.

Here are two small tables ($C_n$ is the species of cycles, corresponding to the cyclic groups, $P^b_n$ is the species of polygons whose edges are alternately coloured red and blue).  For the species of polygons I obtain

$\tilde P_3 = C_3 + E_3 + XE_2$
$\tilde P_4 = 2P_4 + C_4 + P^b_4 + E_2^2$
$\tilde P_5 = P_5 + 2C_5 + XE_2(X^2)$
$\tilde P_6 = 2P_6 + 2C_6 + 2P^b_6$
$\tilde P_7 = P_7 + 3C_7 + XE_2(X^3)$
$\tilde P_8 = 2P_8 + 3C_8 + P^b_8 + \{((1,2)(3,4)(7,8), (1,3)(2,4)(5,6))\}$

The expression $\{((1,2)(3,4)(7,8), (1,3)(2,4)(5,6))\}$ should be interpreted as the species corresponding to the permutation group with the given two generators.  It appears that this (atomic) species cannot be written as a substitution.
For the species of oriented sets I obtain

$\tilde E^\pm_2 = X^2$
$\tilde E^\pm_3 = 3C_3$
$\tilde E^\pm_4 = E^\pm_4 + P^b_4 + 2XC_3$
$\tilde E^\pm_5 = E^\pm_5 + 2C_5 + X^2 C_3 + X P^b_4$
$\tilde E^\pm_6 = E^\pm_6 + 2C_3^2 + 2XC_5 + \{((1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(5,6))\} + \{((1,2,3,4)(5,6))\}$

Questions:

Are there nice expressions for $\tilde P_n$ or $\tilde E^\pm_n$, or at least for their characters?
Is there an efficient way to compute the character of $\tilde F$?
Is there a reasonably efficient way to compute $\tilde F$?
Is this interesting at all?

Comments:
Apparently, the groups appearing in the molecular decomposition of $\tilde F$ are precisely the centralizer subgroups of the group corresponding to $F$.  For the dihedral groups these are listed explicitly in the thesis Parthasarathy, Bhargavi, Conjugacy Classes of Centralizers in Groups, whereas for the alternating groups they are determined in Bhunia, Sushil; Kaur, Dilpreet; Singh, Anupam, $z$-classes and rational conjugacy classes in alternating groups, J. Ramanujan Math. Soc. 34, No. 2, 169–183 (2019). ZBL1469.20002.

Apparently, the groups appearing in the molecular decomposition of $\tilde F$ are precisely the centralizer subgroups.  I know nothing about permutation groups.

The centralizer of a point (or structures as you seem to call them), are $S_{n-1}$'s, for instance.   They are disjoint,  as their intersection is the trivial center for $S_n, n\ge3.$

@non-euclideangeometry, sorry, I do not understand.  The structures are the elements of the set the symmetric group is acting on.  Conversely, given a permutation group, the structures are the cosets, and the action is the coset action.

Yeah,  this terminology is new to me.   Normally the symmetric group is thought to just act on $n$ objects or points.   Like ${1,2,\dots, n}.$

Let $M_G$ be the molecular species with corresponding permutation group $G$.  Let $C_G(g) = \{h\in G| gh = hg\}$ be the centralizer subgroup of $g\in G$.  Finally, let $Conj(G)$ be the set of conjugacy classes of $G$.
Then
$$
\tilde M_G = \sum_{g\in Conj(G)} M_{C_G(g)},
$$
where the sum is over a set of representatives of conjugacy classes.
Proof:
For $a\in Conj(G)$ let $\tilde M_G^a = \{\sigma\cdot (G, a) | \sigma\in\mathfrak S_n\}$.  Then the map $\sigma C_G(a) \mapsto \sigma\cdot(G, a)$ is well defined and an isomorphism between $M_{C_G(a)}$ and $\tilde M_G^a$.
Moreover, $\bigcup_{a\in Conj(G)} \tilde M_G^a = \tilde M_G$, and the union is disjoint.

I can imagine that the statement appears implicitly in the proof of the substitution formula by Joyal.
